# Query data that does not fulfill constraints in table in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, schema, constraint

In Oracle I have a lot of tables in a given schema. Some of the table constraints in the schema have been disabled.

I have to know for all tables in a given schema with any of the constraints deactivated, what are the (data) rows that would not fulfil the deactivated constraints.

### Question

Is there a way to easily collect all the rows that would produce an error if I were to decide to enable the constraints again?

So far, I would try to go constraint by constraint, create a query for each table and run the query. But I wonder whether there is anything that may do the work quickly and less error prone. If possible, the solution should use the information available in view `USER_CONSTRAINTS` or any similar one.

I have checked the `constraint` documentation in Oracle, in which the `constraint` clause may use [`ENABLE NOVALIDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1010237), which allows for having non-compliant rows of data for the existing values until they are modified.

However, I am looking for a solution that would allow me to fix the data before I re-enable the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reporting Constraint Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-schema-objects.html#GUID-1DBBC985-4943-4C75-BFAD-6DECC340088C)

> You must create an appropriate exceptions report table to accept
>   information from the EXCEPTIONS option of the ENABLE clause before
>   enabling the constraint. You can create an exception table by
>   executing the UTLEXCPT.SQL script or the UTLEXPT1.SQL script.
>
> The following statement attempts to validate the PRIMARY KEY of the
>   dept table, and if exceptions exist, information is inserted into a
>   table named EXCEPTIONS:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE dept ENABLE PRIMARY KEY EXCEPTIONS INTO EXCEPTIONS;
> ```
>
> If duplicate primary key values exist in the dept table and the name
>   of the PRIMARY KEY constraint on dept is sys_c00610, then the
>   following query will display those exceptions:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM EXCEPTIONS;
> ```
>
> The following exceptions are shown:
>
> ```
> fROWID               OWNER      TABLE_NAME      CONSTRAINT
> ------------------  ---------  --------------  -----------
> AAAAZ9AABAAABvqAAB  SCOTT      DEPT            SYS_C00610 
> AAAAZ9AABAAABvqAAG  SCOTT      DEPT            SYS_C00610
> ```